# How do I alter write permissions from root to specific user on a Samba raspberry pi nas using an exfat drive?

Tags: samba, readwrite, exfat

I've set up a nas with a raspberry pi and an exfat drive.
Unfortunately I can only read from my computer and not write since only root has write permissions on the drive and I cannot alter them using 'chown', it tells me "operation not permitted". I am guessing this has to do with the exfat filesystem.

I can force user to be root in the Samba config and that works but that doesn't seem secure. I want a non-public nas that works only with a password and allows that user to write.

```
$ ls -al /mnt/usb1
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 131072 Oct 15 13:59  .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Oct 14 22:13  ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 131072 Oct 14 18:45 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 131072 Oct 14 18:41  .fseventsd
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 131072 Oct 15 13:35  shared
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 131072 Oct 14 18:41  .Spotlight-V100
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 131072 Oct 14 18:39 'System Volume Information'


$ ls -al /mnt/usb1/shared
total 384
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 131072 Oct 15 13:35 .
rwxr-xr-x  7 root root 131072 Oct 15 13:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 131072 Oct 15 13:33 Music

$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
[share]
path = /mnt/usb1/shared
writeable=Yes
read only=no
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
public=no
browseable = yes
```

Comment: your question does not belong here ... it is a Linux question, not a Raspberry Pi specific question

Comment: This is definitely do-able, but to help me with my answer, please add the following information to your question: **Your entry in /etc/fstab showing how you mounted the drive you wish to share under Samba.**  In the meantime, you may want to try [this *recipe*](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FileShare.md) - it's always worked for me.